# Plink is showing permission denied error

Tags: vbscript, qtp, plink

I am able execute a sh file using PuTTY. But when I try to execute the same in `plink` it's throwing a permission denied error.

I am able to execute basic command like la - let or PWD and more using `plink`.

But only sh files are throwing permission denied error.

In command prompt I typed this

```
plink -ssh -l username -pw password host -m input.txt>  output.txt
```

If I mention `ls -lrt` it's working fine. But running sh file is not working.

No antivirus.

Input text:

```
./start shellscriptname.sh
```

Output:

Username and path and

> permission denied keyboard interactive

Comment: There is no sh file in your command line. Please show the code that's being executed and the error you're getting.

Comment: I mention in the input.txt file. Because I have to move to one and I need to execute the sh file

Comment: Yes, that was already clear to me. Please *show* the content of `input.txt` and the error message.

Comment: .start shellname.sh this command in input text and error in output text is permission denied

Comment: I cant add full details of output

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy/paste content and error message. Don't paraphrase. If there are sensitive information in the output you may obfuscate that, but leave the rest intact.

Comment: The content is permission denied with path and username nothing more

Comment: I edited the question with input and output text

Comment: *permission denied keyboard-interactive* means that the SSH server doesn't accept password authentication. Try public key authentication instead. If literal commands work, but your script doesn't, it means what you're executing tries to establish *another* SSH connection and fails. What exactly is `./start`? Is it a shell script? What is its content?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a dash before `pw`.

It should be:

```
plink -ssh -l username -pw password host -m input.txt>  output.txt
```

Comment: If I mention ls - lrt in input text it's showing me the output thanks

Comment: So show us exact contents of your `input.txt` and exact output. I do not think that *"Username and path and permission denied keyboard interactive"* is **exact** output. Or post a screenshot.

Comment: permission denied keyboard interactive this what it's mentioned in the output.i already said what is in the input